# What mean that $x\mapsto g(x,\cdot )$ is continuous $\mathbb R\to L^2(\mathbb R)$?

Tags: real-analysis

What mean that $x\mapsto g(x,\cdot )$ is continuous from $\mathbb R\to L^2(\mathbb R)$ ? Is it $$\lim_{h\to 0}g(x+h,\cdot )=g(x,\cdot ) \ \ ?$$
I'm a bit confuse.

Answer (score 0):

It means that $$\lim_{h\to 0}g(x+h,\cdot )=g(x,\cdot ),$$
in $L^2$ sense, i.e. $$\lim_{h\to \infty }\|g(x+h,\cdot )-g(x,\cdot )\|_{L^2(\mathbb R)}^2=\lim_{h\to 0}\int_{\mathbb R}|g(x+h,y)-g(y)|^2\,\mathrm d y=0.$$

Comment: thanks, I see now.